# EmberJS - Handling events for multiple elements inside a view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a Handlebars template called '`projects`' and a view called '`ProjectsView`' which references the template with the `templateName` property.

This projects template generates a list of `divs` from a model and each div needs to be expanded on a click.

```
{{#each project in model}}
    <div class="project">
        <img src="{{project.logo}}" /> <!-- Execute a different logic for the click event  -->
        <h4>{{project.title}}</h4> <!-- Execute a different logic for this click
{{/each}}
```

I initially used the `action` helper and added a relevant method inside the `actions` hash of the `ProjectsController`. However, the `action` is being executed on all the `divs` in the list instead of just the clicked one.

Previous versions of Ember used to provide a `context` argument for the `action` but it is no longer the case. It turns out the recommended way to handle `DOM` events is within in the view like below.

```
App.ProjectsView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'projects',
    click: function(event) {
        // Do something with the event
    }
})
```

However, it doesn't feel right to write a bunch of `if's` inside the click handler to find if the click event was triggered on an `image` or a `h4` and act accordingly. Is this is the right way of handling events or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I would think you would have the controller determine which element triggered the event and have the action limited to that element. Are you sending the event from the view to a controller?

Comment: @Anthony No, I'll look into it now. But wouldn't this be similar to what I'm doing already? Instead of testing the event target inside the view, we are moving this logic to the controller.

Comment: Yes, but the difference being instead of having an event listener for each div, you would have the controller apply the  event action on only the element that triggered the event. It would use the property of the event object that reflects the origin so that instead of the action being applied to all elements that are tied to the listener.

Comment: @Anthony Lets say I have a div, and a couple of other elements nested in this div. I want to attach a click event listener to this containing div. If I understand you correctly, you are saying that I should use a click handler in the view and then forward this event to the relevant controller and handle it there.

But this click event will be triggered upon a click on any element inside the view where as I only want to listen to click events on this specific div. Currently, the only way I can think of achieving this is to filter the events using event.target. Correct?

Comment: Right, and since the model of each div for that event action is the same, you could then find the parent of the target of class `project` for any div-level action. Have the action contained to that div (basically the same idea as "context" you said used to be built in)

Comment: This way your code stays small and generic, you just have a generic reference in the action that says "use the parent div of the target" instead of "apply to all listening elements"

Comment: Thank you, it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instead use `App.ProjectsView` as a [CollectionView](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CollectionView.html) with each project as it's child view.

```
App.ProjectsView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'projects',
    itemViewClass: 'App.ProjectView'
})
```

You can handle actions in your child views directly using the `target=view` [option in action helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#toc_specifying-a-target).

Since you want to do DOM related tasks (expand/collapse), handling the actions in the views will help as you can get a jQuery object of the view using `this.$()`.